# What could you give to a Hawk animal companion to improve their battle effectiveness?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment, animal-companions

An idea I had was poisoning their talons, but one would have to keep dapping their talons in poison each encounter. Anything else you can think of?

For a Ranger with a Hawk/Falcon animal companion.

Comment: Related: [How can I improve the survivability of the Beast Master's animal companion?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142971)

Comment: Related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92205/

Comment: Looking at "Unearthed Arcana: The Ranger,Revised" I've realized that you can provide an animal companion two skills. This I think makes the question even more relevant, important to be available for people.

Comment: @AmethystWizard “It’s important” isn’t a reason to reopen a question. If you want this reopened it needs to be revised so that it’s no longer asking for a list of ideas. If you really just want ideas though, you’ll want to ask this on a forum instead of on this site. (We have [a list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) to make finding one easier.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not incredibly practical, but you could take magic initiate feat and take Warlock/Druid cantrip Magic Stone. Depending on your DM's ruling, he may allow the hawk to drop magic stones onto enemies?

Magic Stone states:

> You or someone else can make a ranged spell attack with one of the
>   pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling.

If your DM is comfortable with allowing the hawk to drop magic stones (throw them), then it's a free 1d6+Wis. Once again, not overtly practical, but a thought!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take our [tour] if you have a minute. Hope to see you around. Happy gaming!